# Install rbenv or Homebrew first?

Tags: ruby

tl;dr: Have never hitherto installed either `rbenv` or Homebrew on my macOS machine; which would be considered best practice, or what are the pros/cons of each?

Unabridged: Somehow, in my 13 yr. development career and 13 yr. tenure as a Mac user, I've never installed installed a package manager. And I'm also setting myself to learn Ruby/Rails in coming weeks/months. So I'm aiming to set up both.  But there are some who would recommend using Homebrew to set up `rbenv`;  and of course, you can install rubies via `rbenv` (and `ruby-build`), and then possibly set up your Homebrew install from a non-system ruby)?

Is there an unequivocally better choice in these two? I'm a JavaScript developer, and I've set up both `nvm` and now `nodenv` w/o package manager. For symmetry of experience I have a slight inclination to do `rbenv` first, but those wiser in this than me are free to advise to the contrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installation instructions for rbenv on MacOS assume Homebrew is already installed so this should be done first.

https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-macos